# DB2 function- Decimal returning incorrect figure... 20.7342 from DB returning 20. Expected 21

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have written one DB2 function-

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functionName(pID BIGINT)
 RETURNS DECIMAL
 LANGUAGE SQL 
 NOT DETERMINISTIC 
 NO EXTERNAL ACTION 

    BEGIN atomic 
        -- declare variable(s)
        DECLARE result DECIMAL;
        SET (result) = 
            (..
             .. -- statement
             ..);   
        -- still no number found => return 0
        IF result IS NULL THEN
            RETURN 0;
        END IF;

        RETURN result;
    END
```

Here if the value in DB is 12.7, it is returning 12. Expected is 13.
And if value is 12.64 -- Returning 12--Expected is 13.
And if value is 12.51 -- Returning 12--Expected is 13.

Comment: `return round(result,0)`?

Comment: Which function do you use? Provide the function WITH the code which converts the data! How should we guess what you do with this limited information?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functionName(pID BIGINT)
RETURNS DECIMAL
LANGUAGE SQL 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 

 BEGIN atomic 
  
  DECLARE result DECIMAL;
  SET (result) = 
   (select oPid from personMondel pp where pp.personId=pID); 
  
  IF result IS NULL THEN
   RETURN 0;
  END IF;
  
  RETURN result;
 END

Answer (score 0):

You have a native function for this.

```
   select CEIL(yourcolumn) from your table
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples given do not make conspicuous, whether the effect that is desired, of which two were offered already [ROUND in an answer and CEILING in a comment under the OP] might be desirable, but the following may suffice:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functionName(pID BIGINT)
RETURNS DECIMAL /* probably should explicitly state scale & precision */
LANGUAGE SQL 
NOT DETERMINISTIC  /* for sure ¿or perhaps came from some template? */
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
 return
   coalesce( /* or IfNull( */
        round( … /* obtain decimal scalar result with non-zero scale */
             , 0 /* this may be the default\optional-argument */
             ) /* round( */
           , 0
           ) /* coalesce( or IfNull( */
```